# MySQL on update set value of one column as sum of two columns

Tags: mysql

I'm developing a pos application and I thought that I could reduce the amount of code in the program and prevent errors by letting the mysql server do some work for me. What I would like to is MySQL to calculate the value of one column based on the other value added to table.

My MySQL table looks like this:

---

### | id | tax_group | amount | balance | date |

As I understand it, you can add triggers to the table that when a new amount value is added, it would automatically count the balance (ie. *balance += amount*). This would also prevent the user manipulate the taxes. However, I don't know how to do this. I've looked the MySQL documentation, but it didn't help.

I'd appreciate greatly if you could help me.

Comment: Could you please provide some sample data and what will happen when you do insert/update from those sample data ?

Comment: Let's say the balance is 10. Then I do a command from the program
INSERT INTO tax.sales VALUES(NULL,1,10.00). 
Then the server would calculate the balance value (10+10) and would insert it automatically to the row. Is that possible?

Comment: and if you update amount to say `20.00` then what will happen to balance ?

Comment: Then the balance would be 20.00 plus the balance value on the previous line.

Comment: there's an argument for storing the gross amount (because taxes can change) but not the gross balance, which can be easily derived from other data. Also, while it's true that wheels need reinventing, have you reviewed the state-of-the-art.

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need for trigger.  when you update amount then you can set balance to old balance + new_amount

```
update tax_sales set amount=20, balance=balance+amount where id=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

this could help you, but I think the math-part is not really what you want, but you'll be able to modify it!

```
create trigger insert_amount 
before insert on my_table for each row
  set NEW.balance  = NEW.balance + NEW.amount;


create trigger update_amount 
before update on my_table for each row
  set NEW.balance  = NEW.balance + NEW.amount;
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have 2 triggers to accomplish this.
The first one when you add a new record and the 2nd one while you update a record. The triggers could be as

```
delimiter //

create trigger before_ins_cal_balance before insert on your_table_name
for each row
begin
 set new.balance = new.amount ;
end;//

delimiter ;



delimiter //

create trigger before_upd_cal_balance before update on your_table_name
for each row
begin
 if new.amount <> old.amount then
    set new.balance = old.balance+new.amount ;
 end if;
end;//

delimiter ;
```

Here the first one will set the same value as amount to balance, and the 2nd one while updating will set the new balance as previous balance + old amount. Note that the balance amount will be updated in the 2nd case if only the amount is changed, else it will have the previous value